# Cant print elements of arraylist or list

Tags: c#

When i call ReadList function it dosent print the elements,what i am doing wrong?i tried even with normal list.What i want to do is if i create 2 accounts by CreateAccount function, i want to print them both through ReadList.

```
namespace Bank
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main()
        {
            int option;
            do
            {

                Menu1 menu1 = new Menu1();
                Account account = new Account();
                option = menu1.CallMenu1();
                if (option == 1)
                {
                    account.CreateAccount();
                }else if (option == 2) {
                    account.ReadList();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (true);
        }

    }

    class Account
    {
        int AccountNumber { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        float Balance { get; set; }



        public void CreateAccount()
        {
            int AccountNumberInput;
            string NameInput;
            float BalanceInput;
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

            Console.WriteLine("put id");
            AccountNumberInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("type name");
            NameInput =Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("type balance");
            BalanceInput = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            list.Add(AccountNumberInput);
            list.Add(NameInput);
            list.Add(BalanceInput);
        }
        public void ReadList()
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            foreach (string c in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, why are you still using `ArrayList` at all? It was superceded by `List<T>` in 2005, 12 years ago.

Comment: `ArrayList list = new ArrayList();  foreach (string c in list)` - you never put anything into `list` so what are you expecting to print out? - The `list` variable in `ReadList` is **not** the same one as in `CreateAccount`

Answer (score 2):

Your `CreateAccount` method does this:

- Creates a new list
- Populates the list
- Does nothing with the list

Your `ReadList` method does this:

- Creates a new (empty) list
- Prints the contents of the list

The list created in `CreateAccount()` is never communicated outside the method - how do you expect the `ReadList()` method to know about it?

The simplest change would be to make `CreateAccount()` *return* the list it creates, then change `ReadList` to *accept* an `ArrayList` as a parameter. You'd change your `Main` method to store the result of `CreateAccount` in a local variable, then pass it to `ReadList` when it calls that.

However, beyond that:

- I would avoid using `ArrayList` in any new code. It was superceded many, many years ago by `List<T>`.
- Your `CreateAccount` method should surely do what it says: create an *account*. It should probably be a static method returning an `Account`... then your `ReadList` method could just be a `PrintDetails` instance method without any parameters, because you would call it *on* the instance returned by `CreateAccount`.
- You should consider what you want to do if you someone tries to print the account before creating it...

Answer (score 0):

Because your class is wrong. You are initialising your list inside one of your methods. Once your method completes execution, everything inside it is unloaded from the memory.

For this to work, you have to add a field/property to the class itself that contains the data and can be used by all the methods of the class

```
class Account
{
    int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    float Balance { get; set; }
    //added this line
    private ArrayList list {get;set;}


    public void CreateAccount()
    {
        int AccountNumberInput;
        string NameInput;
        float BalanceInput;
        //notice this
        list = new ArrayList();

        Console.WriteLine("put id");
        AccountNumberInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("type name");
        NameInput =Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("type balance");
        BalanceInput = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        list.Add(AccountNumberInput);
        list.Add(NameInput);
        list.Add(BalanceInput);
    }
    public void ReadList()
    {
        //removed ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        foreach (string c in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
}
```